# Rails ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers undocumented in 5.1+

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html (and versions before down to 5.1) the documentation of the helpers (get, post, etc) states e.g:

```
Performs a GET request with the given parameters. See #process for more details.
```

I can find no documentation for #process - the code doesn't seem to even be implemented that way any more. Am I missing something, or is this a doc bug?

Comment: Please give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html#method-i-process

I still consider this is poor - it isn't Googlable and I only found it by looking through the source.